# Proximal Operator of the Indicator Function (Show It Is the Projection Operator)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Let ${C \subset \mathbb{R}^n}$ be closed, convex, and nonempty. How might one show that the proximal mapping of the indicator function of $C$ is in fact the projection operator on to $C$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proximal operator of the indicator function $\iota_C$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
prox_{\iota_C}(z)=
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{argmin}}
& & \frac{1}{2}\|x-z\|^2_2  + \iota_C(x) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
which can be re-written as:
\begin{equation*}
prox_{\iota_C}(z)=
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x \in C}{\text{argmin}}
& & \frac{1}{2}\|x-z\|^2_2   \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
which is nothing but the projection of $z$ onto $C$.